# Ionic with VS 2015 update 3

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework

[image]

I have the VS 2015 installed, building an Ionic app and use the `ionic serve` to host and unit test the app, everything is okay, however I see many temp files created in my solution.

my question is: how to disable them? is it possible if I don't want to have the temp files created?

Comment: no, ionic 1, latest version

Comment: I am also using ionic 1 and didn't encouter this issue before :D

Comment: using VS also? 2015?

Comment: anyone has any idea?

Comment: same issue here .. still looking for the reason